# How to hide from the public "comments and likes from friends" underneath my Facebook cover photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

My Facebook friends list is set to "friends only" so the public cannot see this.  They can, however, see who SOME of my friends are by viewing the comments and likes from friends underneath my cover photo (which cannot be changed from public).

How do I change the settings such that these particular comments and friend likes are hidden from the public?

Comment: Very good question. Wish I knew of a way.